# NBDroid - Netbeans and Firebase

Tags: java, android, netbeans, firebase, google-play-services

I build Android apps using Netbeans and the NBDroid plugin.

After the latest google play services update, to version 30, the **google-play-services.jar is now missing** from the Android SDK folder and a few **.aar** files have taken its position.

I managed to convert the .aar files to .jar and import them in my application libs folder but I still **cannot make the Firebase analytics to work**. The app builds perfectly fine but when I try to debug it in my Phone (Samsung Galaxy A5) it does not run at all..

Has anybody solve this matter?